# Ajax call to update div on failure, or redirect to page on success

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, jquery-validate

**Background:**

I have a popup which lets me create a company, this popup has a text field called company name, and this is a required field (using the `[Required]` data annotation on the backing view model).

```
<div class="popup-editor">
    <h4 class="popup-title">
    Add new Company</h4>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Company", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "popup-editor", OnSuccess = "$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');" },))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true);
        <table>
            <tr>
               <td class="label">
                   Company Name
               </td>
               <td class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
               </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="popup-buttons">
            <a href="#" onclick="return togglePopupEditor();">Cancel</a>
            <input type="submit" value="Add Company" />
        </div>
     }
</div>
```

Now the validation works correctly and the ajax lets me show an error message in the popup when the name field is empty.

**Problem:**

When there are no validation errors I need to be able to redirect to a new page (company details page), but instead this page is inserted into the div where the popup contents were. For example:

```
public ActionResult Create(CreateCompanyModel model)
{
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return PartialView("_AddCompanyEditor");
        }

        Company c = CompanyService.Create(model.Name);
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { companyId = c.Id });
}
```

Is there any way to either; force a complete redirect for the entire page, or switch to a standard HTML form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. Browsers handle AJAX redirects without notifying the calling javascript of what happened. One option would be to return a small snippet of HTML that contains a javascript tag that redirects the page. The jQuery handling on the client side should pick that up and run it.

Most other options would involve changing your AjaxOptions to run a method that watches for something specific in the results and acts in a different way depending on the response. For the project I work on currently, we have all of our AJAX requests go through a special "event framework," so that different actions can be performed depending on which events get returned from the controller action.

Comment: Thanks! I used your first suggestion, not the ideal solution but works well.